# Spring AOP - @AfterReturning does not work

Tags: spring, spring-aop, spring-aspects

I have a Java method, getAllItems(), and I created an aspect method, which is called after getAllItems() ends.

```
@Repository
@Scope("prototype")
public class ItemDao {
    // not using database connection for this question; the program works fine, except aspects
    public List<String> getIAllItems() {
        List<String> items = new ArrayList();
        items.add("item1");
        return items;
    }
}
```

The aspect class is this:

```
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import java.util.List;

@Aspect
public class MyAspects {

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* ro.telacad.dao.ItemDao.getIAllItems(..))", returning="items")
    public void afterGetAllItems(List<String> items) {
        System.out.println(items);
    }
}
```

So, after calling getAllItems() I expect to see in console printed "[item1]", but the aspect method is not called. There is no error in console, and the application, except aspects, works fine. So I consider all the spring beans are created.

In appConfig.xml, the beans are declared like this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="ro.telacad.*" />
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
```

My question is what I did wrong for aspects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyAspects` is not picked up by Spring's component scanning as it does not have the `@Component` annotation, and neither has [`@Aspect`](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/aspectj5rt-api/org/aspectj/lang/annotation/Aspect.html). [`@Repository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html) does have the annotation.

Either add the `@Component` annotation to `MyAspects`, or explicitly declare the bean in your XML config:

```xml
<bean id="myAspects" class="com.yourpackage.MyAspects">
...
</bean>
```